# Is it idiomatic Ruby to add an assert( ) method to Ruby's Kernel class?

Tags: ruby, assert, xunit

I'm expanding my Ruby understanding by coding an equivalent of Kent Beck's xUnit in Ruby.  Python (which Kent writes in) has an assert() method in the language which is used extensively.  Ruby does not.  I think it should be easy to add this but is Kernel the right place to put it?

BTW, *I know of the existence of the various Unit frameworks in Ruby* - this is an exercise to learn the Ruby idioms, rather than to "get something done".

Comment: I like problems that do both:  teach you, and get something done.  :)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

No it's not a best practice. The best analogy to assert() in Ruby is just raising

```
 raise "This is wrong" unless expr
```

and you can implement your own exceptions if you want to provide for more specific exception handling

Comment: You can also use `fail if [expr]`, if you like, which throws a Runtime Error.

Comment: `fail` is an alias for `raise`, isn't it?  They both give `RuntimeError`.  (Maybe one is more idiomatic?)

Comment: See "fail" here:  http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html

Comment: This makes it hard to take asserts out of production code, as some wish to do.

Comment: It's good if your software fails hard and fast in production, I consider silenced exceptions a terrible copy of the "catch all exceptions" workaround. It's usually the first terrible bandaid applied to terrible code when things break.

Comment: Assertions and exceptions are different things.

Comment: @Julik No it's not, assertions might warn you of something suspicious, that's not supposed to happen, but that might not break anything immediately, and it's good to break hard and fast during testing. In production the goal should be to never have to barf backtraces at your users.

Comment: @nus Assertions are not for warning, they're for ensuring something is *always* true at that place. If your assertion fails in production you most definitely want to abort.

Comment: @nus, +1 to Yarin. Warning should be implemented as logging.

Answer (score 37):

I think it is totally valid to use asserts in Ruby. But you are mentioning two different things:

- xUnit frameworks use `assert` methods for checking your tests expectations. They are intended to be used in your test code, not in your application code.
- Some languages like C, Java or Python, include an `assert` construction intended to be used inside the code of your programs, to check assumptions you make about their integrity. These checks are built inside the code itself. They are not a test-time utility, but a development-time one.

I recently wrote [solid_assert: a little Ruby library implementing a Ruby assertion utility](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/solid_assert) and also [a post in my blog explaining its motivation](http://jorgemanrubia.net/2011/09/19/solid_assert-a-simple-ruby-assertion-utility/). It lets you write expressions in the form:

```
assert some_string != "some value"
assert clients.empty?, "Isn't the clients list empty?"

invariant "Lists with different sizes?" do
    one_variable = calculate_some_value
    other_variable = calculate_some_other_value
    one_variable > other_variable
end
```

And they can be deactivated, so `assert` and `invariant` get evaluated as empty statements. This let you avoid performance problems in production. But note that [The Pragmatic Programmer: from journeyman to master](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) recommends against deactivating them. You should only deactivate them if they really affect the performance.

Regarding the answer saying that the idiomatic Ruby way is using a normal `raise` statement, I think it lacks expressivity. One of the golden rules of assertive programming is not using assertions for normal exception handling. They are two completely different things. If you use the same syntax for the two of them, I think your code will be more obscure. And of course you lose the capability of deactivating them.

Some widely-regarded books that dedicate whole sections to assertions and recommend their use:

- [The Pragmatic Programmer: from Journeyman to Master](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) by Andrew Hunt and David Thomas
- [Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) by Steve McConnell
- *Writing Solid Code* by Steve Maguire

[Programming with
assertions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)
is an article that illustrates well what assertive programming is about and
when to use it (it is based in Java, but the concepts apply to any
language).

Comment: I'd also suggest "Writing Solid Code" by Steve Maguire, which is extremely C oriented, but talks about asserts, testing strategy, and ideas on constructing functions that also apply to method construction.

Answer (score 15):

What's your reason for adding the assert method to the Kernel module? Why not just use another module called `Assertions` or something?

Like this:

```
module Assertions
  def assert(param)
    # do something with param
  end

  # define more assertions here
end
```

If you really need your assertions to be available **everywhere** do something like this:

```
class Object
  include Assertions
end
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test the code but in principle I would do it like this.

Comment: Isn't this monkey patching? You are altering the `Object` class.

Comment: Yeah, that's classical monkey-patching. That's the way to do it, If you really have to make the `assert` method available globally. However, I wouldn't advise anyone to use monkey-patching like this in non-toy projects.

Answer (score 9):

It's not especially idiomatic, but I think it's a good idea. Especially if done like this:

```
def assert(msg=nil)
    if DEBUG
        raise msg || "Assertion failed!" unless yield
    end
end
```

That way there's no impact if you decide not to run with DEBUG (or some other convenient switch, I've used Kernel.do_assert in the past) set.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that you're writing your own testing suite as a way of becoming more familiar with Ruby.  So while Test::Unit might be useful as a guide, it's probably not what you're looking for (because it's already done the job).

That said, python's assert is (to me, at least), more analogous to C's [assert(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/assert/).  It's not specifically designed for unit-tests, rather to catch cases where "this should never happen".

How Ruby's built-in unit tests tend to view the problem, then, is that each individual test case class is a subclass of [TestCase](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit/TestCase.html), and that includes an "assert" statement which checks the validity of what was passed to it and records it for reporting.