# how to put assertions in ruby code

Tags: ruby

I want to use the assertions and put valuidations in my ruby code (e.g: checking if a zip file is created, label is present, message in the text area, etc). I have put a few assert statements like `assert @selenium.is_text_present(textMessage)`, but they don't work.

Please let me know if any ruby gem for assertions is to be installed.

Comment: Please, make sure you've read the [formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), notice that we all are always friendly, and that's why we skip usual "hi/thanks" parts of the messages, and--welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Think this is similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147969/is-it-idiomatic-ruby-to-add-an-assert-method-to-rubys-kernel-class

Answer (score 32):

For simple asserts, you're probably best off rolling your own assert method taking a block:

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > class AssertionError < RuntimeError
ruby-1.9.1-p378 ?>  end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > def assert &block
ruby-1.9.1-p378 ?>  raise AssertionError unless yield
ruby-1.9.1-p378 ?>  end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > assert { 1 > 0 }
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > assert { 5 == 12 }
AssertionError: AssertionError
    from (irb):8:in `assert'
    from (irb):11
    from /Users/mr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

In copypastastable form:

```
class AssertionError < RuntimeError
end

def assert &block
    raise AssertionError unless yield
end

i = 1
assert {i >= 0}
assert { 5 == 12 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using a block as an argument instead of a simple boolean?

Comment: If the assert method checks some other condition (e.g. 'if DEBUG_ENABLED') before doing the "raise... unless yield", then if that condition returns false, the yield won't ever be invoked, and hence the passed-in block won't ever be evaluated. If what the block does is expensive, this could have a big effect on program execution time.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [**solid_assert**](https://rubygems.org/gems/solid_assert) gem to add assertions to Ruby.

**See:**
[solid_assert: A simple Ruby assertion
   utility](http://jorgemanrubia.net/2011/09/19/solid_assert-a-simple-ruby-assertion-utility/)
[Is it idiomatic Ruby to add an assert( ) method to Ruby's Kernel
   class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7481328/165673)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just developing or debugging and need a quick one-liner

`throw 'Error message' unless thing == expected`