# What is an appropriate way to test function input in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have several ruby functions and want to check that the input is correct and also whether the input makes sense. What is a sensible way to do that?

Here's an example with one of the functions I have and what I would like to check

```
# Converts civil time to solar time
# civilT: Time object
# longitude: float
# timezone: fixnum
def to_solarT(civilT,longitude,timezone)
    # pseudo code to check that input is correct
    assert(civilT.class == Time.new(2013,1,1).class)
    assert(longitude.class == 8.0.class)
    assert(timezone.class == 1.class)

    # More pseudocode to check if the inputs makes sense, in this case 
    # whether the given longitude and timezone inputs make sense or whether 
    # the timezone relates to say Fiji and the longitude to Scotland. Done 
    # using the imaginary 'longitude_in_timezone' function
    assert(longitude_in_timezone(longitude,timezone))
end
```

I found a related question here: [how to put assertions in ruby code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264168/how-to-put-assertions-in-ruby-code). Is this the way to go or are there better ways to test function input in ruby?

Comment: `1.class` makes me shiver. `Time.new.class` makes me want to scream and headdesk.

Comment: Why don't your trust your program to pass valid values for the method signature? Rely on unit tests or exceptions, unless you're dealing with tainted data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert` is not standard Ruby method, and is often used by test frameworks, so I don't think it is good to put it in code. Also, it does not make sense to create instances of the classes you want to check the arguments against. More straightforwardly,

```
def to_solarT civilT, longitude, timezone
  raise "Argument error blah blah" unless Time === civilT
  raise "Argument error blah blah" unless Float === longitude
  raise "Argument error blah blah" unless Fixnum === timezone
  ...
end
```

Comment: Great, what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do it this way. Ruby relies heavily on duck-typing. That is, if it quacks like a duck, it is a duck. i.e. Just use the objects you receive and if they do respond correctly, it's fine. If they don't, you can rescue a NoMethodError and show the appropriate output.

Comment: Thanks @pedro for pointing me to duck typing.... heard about it, ignored it so far but will have a look to see what it means.

Comment: Duck typing is when you don't care much about if something is of a specific class, you just expect a behavior, i.e. does the object quack? then just ask it to quack. Don't ask if it is a Duck because you want to use the method quack.

Comment: Ah ok... not so hard to understand afterall :) Cheers